# Catel (MVVM framework) ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, catel

I'm Using [Catel](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel+documentation+Home) to implement a WPF Application.

I have a class that extends from `ObservableCollection` and every time an Item is inserted The UI must be updated.

CODE (*simplified  version*) :

```
  public abstract class LogCollections : ObservableCollection<Log4NetLog>  {

    private readonly Object _locker;

    protected LogCollections() {
        _logChart = new LoggingLevelChart();
        _locker = new object();
    }

    public object Locker {
        get { return _locker; }


    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Log4NetLog item) {
        lock (_locker) {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);

            if (item == null) {
                return;
            }
            Log4NetLog temp = item as Log4NetLog;

            // Updating

            if (temp != null) {

                // Updating
            }
        } //UnLock 
    }

  }
}
```

Until Now I have used [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845.aspx) which is only available in .NET 4.5. Unfortunately I have to compile the Code using .Net 4.

I want to know that, are there anything in Catel framework that solves this kind of problem.

**More Info:**

For This Application The performance is the main issue, since I add many Items to the collection.

**UPDATE:**

using `FastObservableCollection` solves the problem, however the UI freezes for about 5-7 sec as soon as I get out of using.
my guess is that, this is caused by the `Dispatcher`

I have manually overridden the `OnCollectionChanged`:

```
protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  DispatcherHelper.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => base.OnCollectionChanged(e)),
              DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

this is not a good solution. is there a better way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the [FastObservableCollection](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/master/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.NET40/Collections/FastObservableCollection.cs?source=c) in Catel:

```
using (fastCollection.SuspendChangeNotifications())
{
    // TODO: Add and remove all your items here
}
```

As soon as you get out of the using, it will pass it's change notifications

To get around the threading issues, you can use the DispatcherHelper.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply. this solution gave me a new problem. I have explained the new problem in the end of the question. thank you for your time.

Comment: How big is the list when you are updating? Did you try other values than ContextIdle?